# Android - NumberPicker with custom string data shows wrong value?

Tags: android, numberpicker

It is so simple, and it is so hard at the same time.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] values = {"d", "aa", "a", "b"};
    NumberPicker numberPicker = findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
    numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(values);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(3);
    numberPicker.setValue(2); // Want to show "a" in number picker
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Some more cases:

1. If values are {"d", "c", "a", "b"}, the result is "a".
2. If values are {"d", "aaaaa", "a", "b"}, the result is "aaaaaa".
3. If values are {"d", "aa", "c", "b"}, the result is "c".
4. If values are {"d", "b", "a", "aa"}, the result is "a".
5. **If values are {"d", "AA", "a", "c"}, the result is "AA".**
6. **If values are {"d", "ABCDAA, "a", "c"}, the result is "ABCDAA".**

And when I click to anywhere inside the number picker, the "aa"'ish becomes "a" as expected. However, try putting `numberPicker.performClick()` after the `setValue(2)` method won't help.

This looks so simple but it is driving me nuts. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

tyr to create your own function to modify the data to be set on `NumberPicker` before set on `NumberPicker`.This function prevents any string to be substring of any string from the given array to be set on `NumberPicker`

```
modifyDataForNumberPicker(values);
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(values);

private void modifyDataForNumberPicker(String[] dataList){
        int i=0;
        for(String data : dataList){
            int pos = i++;
            dataList[pos] = data+" ";
    }
}
```

the get the value clicked in the NumberPicker

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    String selectedvalue = values[newVal]           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only lead I've found for this problem, thank you! I had a similar problem were my values were "K-59", "K-58", ... "K-01", "K", "K+01"..., "K+58", "K+59".
I wanted the picker to start with displaying "K" but it was impossible to make it do so. It consistently showed the last value ("K+59", which when clicked changed to "K"). All other values were selectable as first display choice.
When I finally found this post I modified the "K" value to be "K" followed by three space characters (since your problem varied with the length of the choices). This made it work, but what a horrible kludge it is!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what's causing this to happen.
Looking in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java) for NumberPicker, within the "getSelectedPos" function (line 1819 at time of writing) we see this:

```
private int getSelectedPos(String value) {
    if (mDisplayedValues == null) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Ignore as if it's not a number we don't care
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < mDisplayedValues.length; i++) {
            // Don't force the user to type in jan when ja will do
            value = value.toLowerCase();
            if (mDisplayedValues[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(value)) {
                return mMinValue + i;
            }
        }
        /*
         * The user might have typed in a number into the month field i.e.
         * 10 instead of OCT so support that too.
         */
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Ignore as if it's not a number we don't care
        }
    }
    return mMinValue;
}
```

This code is used to take user typed input into the NumberPicker and translate it into an actual value from the provided display strings.

I believe that the for loop in the middle of this function is to blame here. As if a value is a sub-string of a previous value within the display list, it will cause the two to fight over which one is displayed.

There's another function that sets the display while/after scrolling hence why scrolling fixes the visuals.

This is why [ismail alaoui's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267878/7372375) works, it causes the subsequent values to no longer be sub-strings of previous ones.